# Fitting different images as done in Ted.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

How resizing and fitting different images in a fixed space as done in http://www.ted.com/talks/browse and search results jinni.com.

Any leads how this can be done, like with jQuery or with php support something.

Thanks

Comment: Ted.com uses Flash, not javascript.
But it should be possible to do this with jQuery.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer, but the `vw=432&vh=240` parameters in the embed code will resize the thumbnails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it's done on the TED website, they use Flash and only one aspect ratio for all the images, which makes the algorithm fairly trivial. For an even more stylish look (and for serious geek points), you could pick a couple of aspect ratios (one square, one portrait, one or two horizontal) and custom-build an algorithm to solve a subset of the 2D [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) efficiently.

Better yet, you could use some nifty algebra to automatically decide which sizes would fit into a rectangle of a specified width and have the algorithm do all the resizing for you automatically. That may sound like NP-hard black magic, but [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) actually had an excellent article about it some time ago. It even has a simple explanation of the math involved and PHP code you can download and modify to your needs:

[Automatic Magazine Layout](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/magazinelayout) -- [Example 1](http://www.alistapart.com/d/magazinelayouts/example1.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The correct term for this display is a [Treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). It may help with your algorithm search. There are several solutions available, including [JavaScript](http://blog.thejit.org/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit-jit/) and [RoR](http://code.qnot.org/svn/projects/acts_as_treemap/).

Even if those solutions don't work for you, the proper term should help you get on track!

Comment: Thanks for the term 'treemap'. I was actually looking wat exactly people call for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Using float:left & a fixed width & height with a clear:both on some images will do the trick.

```
img.big{
 float:left;
 width:100px;
 height: 100px;
}
img.small{
 float:left;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
img.clear{
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to know the backend algorithm/method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe he's looking for an algorithm that will actually perform the picture layout.

You could look into [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net), which appears to do something very similar (although it uses text, not images).

Comment: yeah i'm looking make algorithm/libraries by which this can be done.
Thanks